# sqlite3 : Compare two cells from the same table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE "modules" ( `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` TEXT, `version` TEXT, `deployID` INTEGER )
```

I want to be able to get all the rows from this database where the version is different between different deploy ID's. So, say I have a deploy ID 2 and a deployID 3 - my table might have 2000 odd modules for each of these deploys. I want to only get the rows where the name is the same but the version is different. Is this possible? I thought this query would do it but it seems to be returning me everything - twice!

```
SELECT a.* FROM modules a 
INNER JOIN modules b 
ON a.name == b.name 
WHERE a.version != b.version 
AND a.deployID = 3 
AND b.deployID = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about `deployid`s `2` and `3`:

```
select m.*
from modules m
where 
  m.deployid in (2, 3)
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from modules 
    where 
      name = m.name 
      and
      deployID <> m.deployID 
      and 
      version <> m.version
  )
```

If you don't need this condition:

```
deployID <> m.deployID
```

you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use an exists query here:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM modules m1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modules m2
              WHERE m1.name = m2.name AND
                    m1.deployID <> m2.deployID AND m1.version <> m2.version);
```

Or maybe you want a more specific version:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM modules m1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modules m2
              WHERE m1.name = m2.name AND
                    LEAST(m1.deployID, m2.deployID) = 2 AND
                    GREATEST(m1.deployID, m2.deployID) = 3);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The <> on the deployID is matching not equal deploys. I just want to compare two specific deploys.

Comment: Changing to `SELECT m1.*
FROM modules m1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modules m2
              WHERE m1.name = m2.name AND
                    m1.deployID  = 2 AND m2.deployID = 3 AND m1.version <> m2.version);` equally seems to return all rows in deployID 2 rather than "unique" rows

Comment: @RealWorld You never gave any sample data to your question, leaving us to guess at what you want.  I have given you another more specific query which might work in your case.